# materialize collapsible not expending on click

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Materialize collapsible is not expanding on click. I have initialize it proper even then its not working.
here is my html code:

```
.
.

 <p style="color: #fff; font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif; font-size: 62px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 72px; margin: 0 0 24px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase" id="demo"></p>
  <div class="row"></div>
    <ul class="collapsible popout col s6" id="clap">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    </ul>

  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
.
.
.
```

and this is initialization code

```
  <script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    checkCurrentUser();
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    var elemss = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
    var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elemss, options);

  });
</script>
```

In this code I also have select element but its working fine. Only collapsible is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the undefined `options` variable:

```
var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elemss);
```

The console should always be the first place to look with any problem, if you look in there you'll see 'options is undefined'.

It's a problem with the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `options` from `var instances = M.Collapsible.init(elemss, options);`. That is an undefined variable in your case. According to the docs, if you are to add extra functionalities to your component, you may add an object accordingly, that would replace `options`. So in short terms, `option` is just a placeholder for that object.